# How to append multiple files to formData?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form, and I have an input in the form, I upload several images in this input, like so:

```html
<input type="file" name="gallery" onChange={imageHandler} required multiple />
```

And when I output the images in the console, it correctly displays an array of files, but when I append the images, `formData.append("gallery", images);` it is not saved as an array. It's saved as a File!

```
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);


  const token = localStorage.getItem("TOKEN");

  
  
  const imageHandler = (e) => {
    setImages([...images, e.target.files[0]]);    
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    images.length && console.log(images);
  }, [images]);

  console.log(images);

  const sendDisease = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(images);
    const form = document.getElementById("signUpForm");
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append("gallery", images);

    console.log(formData);

    try {
      const api = "https://localhost/api/v1/website/disease/add";

      const { data } = await axios.post(api, formData, {
        headers: {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
      toast.success(data.message, { autoClose: 15000 });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      toast.error(e.response.data.error, { autoClose: 15000 });
      console.log(e.response.data.error);
    }
  };

  const handleFileSelect = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <form id="signUpForm" className="md-12">
            <h2 className="text-center mb-4 font-weight-bold">Add Disease</h2>

            <div className="form-row mt-4">
              <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="">Add Disease</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="unique_name"
                  required
                  onChange={(e) => setUniqueName(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="">Title</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="title"
                  placeholder="Title"
                  onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                <label for="">Gallery</label>
                <input type="file" name="gallery" onChange={imageHandler} required multiple />
              </div>
            </div>

              <input type="file" name="image" onChange={handleFileSelect} />
            </div>

            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-primary mt-4"
              onClick={sendDisease}
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your input has a `name` attribute set, calling `new FormData(e.currentTarget)` is enough. So no need to call `formData.append()` as the constructor will pick on its own all the images from the `<form>` for you, and other inputs if there are.

The code below would log all your files if you wanna be sure about it. I also created a working Codesandbox for testing.

```js
export default function App() {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);
    console.log(formData.getAll("gallery"));
  };

  return (
    <form id="signUpForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="file" name="gallery" required multiple />
      <button>Sumbit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image]

If it's not working, try changing `formData.append("gallery", images)` to the code below (it's apparently what's needed for PHP servers for example):

```
images.forEach((image) => {
 formData.append('gallery[]', image);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in my case Am using ASP.NET Core and its working fine

```
images.forEach((image) => {
    formData.append('images', image);
});
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProfile([FromForm]  UpdateProfileModel updateProfileModel)
{
   try
   {
       await Task.CompletedTask;
       return Ok("Done.");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {  
      return BadRequest(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

My Modal

```
public class UpdateProfileModel
{
    public List<IFormFile> Images { get; set; } = new List<IFormFile>();
}
```